# Auto-insert and cycle through completions in Emacs company mode

Tags: emacs, company-mode

I want to implement the following behavior:

1. I type the beginning of a word, say "pr"
2. I press TAB
3. It autocompletes to the first available completion, say "print" - without any popups
4. I don't move my caret and I press TAB again, and it selects the second completion **on "pr" - not on "print", which is already present on my current caret position**

Basically, I want to be able to cycle through completions for a symbol with immediate insertion of the completion - without the popup. How would you do that with `company-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling `company-tng-mode` and removing `company-pseudo-tooltip-unless-just-one-frontend` from `company-frontends`, at the same time.